# Android Flutter : I need to set the 'SingleChildScrollView' in the body?

Tags: android, flutter, scrollview, singlechildscrollview

This is my code,I need to set the **SingleChildScrollView** in the body.I want to scroll the entire screen.

```
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      body: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Container(
          child: Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage("assets/images/login.jpg"),
                    fit: BoxFit.contain,
                    alignment: Alignment.topCenter)),
            child: SafeArea(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(height: 20),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back,
                                color: Colors.white, size: 32),
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.pop(context);
                            },
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap you Form widget with singleChildScroll view

Like below

```dart
return Scaffold(
  body: SingleChildScrollView(child:Form(
    key: _formKey,
    child: Container(
      child: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage("assets/images/login.jpg"),
                fit: BoxFit.contain,
                alignment: Alignment.topCenter)),
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back,
                            color: Colors.white, size: 32),
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.pop(context);
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
)
```